# PostgreSQL advisory locks are not working with Doctrine's DBAL

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, dbal

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior when trying to use [advisory locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) in Doctrine's DBAL.

I have a Symfony 2 application in which I want to obtain an advisory lock for some entity. I'm making the following query to obtain the lock:

```sql
SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(83049, 5)
```

Via the following code in PHP:

```php
/** @var Doctrine\DBAL\Connection  */
protected $connection;

public function lock()
{
    return $this->connection->fetchColumn(
        "SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock({$this->getTableOid()}, {$this->entity->getLockingId()})"
    );
}
```

I've created the following script to test the concurrency:

```php
// Obtaining the lock.
$locker->lock();

// Doing something for ten seconds.
sleep(10);
```

However, when I run it concurrently, it looks like every instance is successfully getting the lock. Also, after request is terminated, it looks like lock is automatically released, even when I've not called `unlock()`.

Why it behaving that way?

Does doctrine use single connection for all requests?

Does doctrine releases the locks automatically after script is terminated?

Answer (score 2):

> 13.3.4. Advisory Locks
>
> PostgreSQL provides a means for creating locks that have
>   application-defined meanings. These are called advisory locks, because
>   the system does not enforce their use — it is up to the application to
>   use them correctly. Advisory locks can be useful for locking
>   strategies that are an awkward fit for the MVCC model. For example, a
>   common use of advisory locks is to emulate pessimistic locking
>   strategies typical of so-called "flat file" data management systems.
>   While a flag stored in a table could be used for the same purpose,
>   advisory locks are faster, avoid table bloat, and are automatically
>   cleaned up by the server at the end of the session.
>
> There are two ways to acquire an advisory lock in PostgreSQL: at
>   session level or at transaction level. Once acquired at session level,
>   an advisory lock is held until explicitly released or the session
>   ends. Unlike standard lock requests, session-level advisory lock
>   requests do not honor transaction semantics: a lock acquired during a
>   transaction that is later rolled back will still be held following the
>   rollback, and likewise an unlock is effective even if the calling
>   transaction fails later. A lock can be acquired multiple times by its
>   owning process; for each completed lock request there must be a
>   corresponding unlock request before the lock is actually released.
>   Transaction-level lock requests, on the other hand, behave more like
>   regular lock requests: they are automatically released at the end of
>   the transaction, and there is no explicit unlock operation. This
>   behavior is often more convenient than the session-level behavior for
>   short-term usage of an advisory lock. Session-level and
>   transaction-level lock requests for the same advisory lock identifier
>   will block each other in the expected way. If a session already holds
>   a given advisory lock, additional requests by it will always succeed,
>   even if other sessions are awaiting the lock; this statement is true
>   regardless of whether the existing lock hold and new request are at
>   session level or transaction level.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've missed the `automatically cleaned up by the server at the end of the session` part. But why multiple clients can obtain the same lock simultaneously?

Comment: it starts to wait another transaction when tries to update locked row.